# Deploying to remote linux JBoss server, from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, deployment, jboss, remote-server

My development computer is Windows. I want to deploy some JBoss sample web applications from Eclipse (on Windows) to my remote JBoss server running on CentOS. They both have JBoss and Java installed. I think that since they have different operating systems though, Eclipse doesn't see that CentOS has the required JBoss packages. Under the "new server" options, when I entered the CentOS server, I specified that this was a Unix server. Is there any way that I can get this to work, or am I at a dead end? By the way, I can remotely browse through the file structure or use the command line, of the server, just fine, in Eclipse.

Thanks,

Here are some errors that I received:

16:19:43,489 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.network.public: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.network.public: JBAS015810: failed to resolve interface public

16:19:48,341 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS016005: Starting Services for CDI deployment: ticket-monster.war

16:19:48,361 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Version] (MSC service thread 1-4) WELD-000900 1.1.5 (AS71)

16:19:48,431 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015954: Admin console is not enabled

16:19:48,431 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started (with errors) in 6743ms - Started 185 of 308 services (75 services failed or missing dependencies, 47 services are passive or on-demand)

16:19:48,631 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "ticket-monster.war" was rolled back with failure message JBAS014750: Operation handler failed to complete

16:19:48,631 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010409: Unbound data source [jboss/datasources/ticket-monsterDS]

16:19:48,681 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment ticket-monster.war in 53ms

16:19:48,681 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => "JBAS014750: Operation handler failed to complete"}}

Answer (score 3):

It's too late to answer, but may it will help someone else. In my case below works :-

To get rid of this :

> MSC000001  : failed to resolve interface public

**Check your JBoss Standalone.xml**

Whether it contains IP address of your machine or not :-

```
<subsystem>
   ...
    <alias name="your IP Address"/>
   ...
</subsystem>

<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:your IP Address}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:your IP Address}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="unsecure">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:your IP Address}"/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>
```

likewise check whole standalone.xml & replace **localhost** or **IP** with the current IP of machine.

Double click on JBoss server to check **Host Name : Your IP**